# What is the oldest quote or poem in known history?

Tags: ancient-history, language, quotes, writing, script

What is the oldest quote, poem, words of wisdom ever written in known history?

I'm guessing it's Kemetian or Babylonian.

I've read some on the internet that I know from memory but cannot verify them, such as the following,

"A contented mind is a hidden treasure."

- Pharoah Akhenaten ~1350BC

"Be still my heart. You have known worse than this."

- Homer 1100BC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Guinness Book of World Records, as cited by [Wikipedia's list of oldest known documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_oldest_documents):

> ... the oldest surviving love poem, a balbale, in the world is of Sumerian origin and written in cuneiform, discovered in Nippur, dated to 2031 BCE, called Istanbul #2461 by archaeologists. ...
>
> > Bridegroom, dear to my heart,
> > Goodly is your beauty, honeysweet,
> > Lion, dear to my heart,
> > Goodly is your beauty, honeysweet.